# Нужно ли ставить тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Купившему три книги и более, — скидка!

Comment: Тире ладно, запятая-то зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно.

Желательно подчеркнуть интонационным тире слово "скидка".
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94

Кроме того, пропущено сказуемое "будет". Так что тире довольно логично.

Но запятая там не должна стоять.